# Select/Dropdownlist is not displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, html-select

I have 4 drop-down lists on my page but for some odd reason streetid is not visible when townid is visible I can't understand what the link is. Would really appreciate it if someone would be able to clarify the matter.

**View Code**

```
<h2>Create</h2>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function GetRegions(_countryid) {
    var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
    $("#regionid").html(procemessage).show();
    var url = "/Citizens/GetRegions/";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { countryid: _countryid },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            var markup = "<option value='0'>Select Region</option>";
            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
            }
            if (markup == "<option value='0'>Select Region</option>")
            {
                markup = "<option value='0'>No Region Data available for Country</option>";
            }
            $("#regionid").html(markup).show();
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });

}
function GetTowns(_regionid) {
    var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
    $("#townid").html(procemessage).show();
    var url = "/Citizens/GetTowns/";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { regionid: _regionid },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            var markup = "<option value='0'>Select Town</option>";
            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
            }
            if (markup == "<option value='0'>Select Town</option>") {
                markup = "<option value='0'>No Town Data available for Region</option>";
            }
            $("#townid").html(markup).show();
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });

}
function GetStreets(_townid) {
    var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
    $("#streetid").html(procemessage).show();
    var url = "/Citizens/GetStreets/";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { townid: _townid },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            var markup = "<option value='0'>Select Street</option>";
            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
            }
            if (markup == "<option value='0'>Select Street</option>") {
                markup = "<option value='0'>No Street Data available for Town</option>";
            }
            $("#streetid").html(markup).show();
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });

}
</script>
@Using (Html.BeginForm())
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Citizen</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(True, "", New With { .class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.CountryId, "Country", htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("CountryID", Nothing, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "form-control", .onchange = "javascript:GetRegions(this.value);"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.CountryId, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.RegionId, "Region", htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
         <div class="col-md-10">
            <select id="regionid" name="regionid" onchange="javascript:GetTowns(this.value);" >
                </select>

             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.RegionId, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.TownId, "Town", htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
         <div class="col-md-10">
             <select id="townid" name="townid" onchange="javascript:GetStreets(this.value);" />
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.TownId, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.StreetId, "Street", htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
         <div class="col-md-10">
             <select id="streetid" name="streetid" />
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.StreetId, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
         </div>
     </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
End Using
```

**In Controller**

```
 <HttpPost>
    Public Function GetRegions(CountryId As String) As ActionResult
        Dim regions = _db.Regions.Where(Function(r) r.CountryId = CountryId).ToList
        Dim slstRegions As New SelectList(regions, "Id", "Region1", 0)
        Return Json(slstRegions)
    End Function

    <HttpPost>
    Public Function GetTowns(RegionId As Integer) As ActionResult
        Dim towns = _db.Towns.Where(Function(t) t.RegionId = RegionId).ToList
        Dim slstTowns As New SelectList(towns, "Id", "Town1", 0)
        Return Json(slstTowns)
    End Function

    <HttpPost>
    Public Function GetStreets(TownId As Integer) As ActionResult
        Dim streets = _db.Streets.Where(Function(t) t.TownId = TownId).ToList
        Dim slstStreets As New SelectList(streets, "Id", "Street1", 0)
        Return Json(slstStreets)
    End Function

    ' GET: Citizens/Create
    Function Create() As ActionResult
        ViewBag.AddressId = New SelectList(GetMyAddresses(_db, User.Identity.GetUserId()), "Id", "House")
        ViewBag.NameId = New SelectList(_db.Names, "Id", "Name1")
        ViewBag.SurnameId = New SelectList(_db.Surnames, "Id", "Surname1")
        ViewBag.CountryId = New SelectList(_db.Countries.OrderBy(Function(c) c.country1), "Id", "Country1")
        Return View(New CitizenModel)
    End Function
```

Comment: When making this call to set the html: $("#streetid").html(markup).show(); Can you confim that the markup is valid for the options?

Comment: @loanburger Yes just put it in an alert to check the markup is loading correctly although that has nothing to do with the question. The problem is that the select is not visible on screen so even though it goes into the JavaScript it will not be able to set it.

Comment: What I was checking is if some data for the options: "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>"; may be coming through as invalid, it may corrupt your markup which could result in the select not being closed property and this may cause it not to show. - If you use element inspector in your browser - can you see the select in the markup?  have a play with the CSS and see if you can manipulate it in showing.

Comment: @loanburger no the select isn't there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that I did find to my problem although not to my liking was to set something so it isn't blank

```
<select id="streetid" name="streetid" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">Select Country</option>
</select>
```

Then I just overwrite the value when I am applying JavaScript. If anyone has a cleaner solution please do tell me.